# Alternative representation of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am tasked to propose another representation of this circuit such that the meshes and the nodes are more clear:

[image]

I know that I should put the each charge in parallel with its corresponding current-source, but here is my question, is the current between the charge X and Y non-zero? Is the current between the two centrales -the bottom wire that connects them - also non-zero or is it zero because it has no path to return? What is the purpose of the right-most wire that connects the upper node of charge Y and the ground of centrale B?

Quick re-implementation in multisim, i can see that both the circuits arent independent and the wires connecting the bottom centrals and the upper charges got current running through them, also the right-most wire isnt just for decoration it also have current running through it [image]

After doing the current -> voltage transformation is this the correct representation? : [image]

Comment: The right-most wire, and the general circuit layout, are there to confuse the student.  If you re-draw the circuit correctly all will become clear.

Comment: @PeterBennett what do you mean by the general circuit layout , also how would i redraw the circuit correctly ?

Comment: Try to redraw the circuit yourself. In fact, you have two independent circuits.

Comment: oh really i had that suspicion while diagnosing the circuit, but why though? @G36

Comment: Redraw it and you will see why.

Comment: redraw to convention ... V+ at top ... GND at bottom ... input at one side ... output at other side ... you just have to pick one of the nodes to be the GND reference

Comment: I think you are very much misusing the word "Charge".

Comment: @MarcusMüller i know, "Charge" here means a load, an active device, but its already inprinting in the scheme so i cant change it sorry

Comment: @jsotola i dont understand the convention , whats V+ in that circuit?

Comment: No, "load" means something else, too, in general. And there is zero active devices in your schematic, aside from the sources. Please don't use the wrong terminology.

Comment: @MarcusMüller just edit the problem if you want, ah i meant passive devices, but also the current source are active components

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI there isn't a V+ as a power supply per se, but there is GND

Comment: @jsotola and where is that ground as you said? is it in between the two centrales?

Comment: No, your representation is not correct. Take a look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekjzi.png And Franc's equivalent circuit is also correct (source transformation).  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/source-transformation/ Thevenin is not needed.

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI you pick one of the nodes to be the GND reference point ... choose one that connects to the greatest number of components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest representation without making any changes is the following:

[image]

Comment: ah i see, but how is that equivalent to the original? is there a process to make such invariant transformations?

Comment: We need to make sure that the connections are as short as possible. The electrical circuit is often made up of copper conductors that can be bent to our liking as well as the terminals of passive and non-passive components. For example, if two resistors are in parallel, obviously I will connect them close to each other. But no one is stopping me from keeping one in one direction and the other in another direction, always with the clamps tied as if they were tight to each other. In short, a mesh can be deformed to our liking while maintaining the starting components.

Answer (score 0):

Apply The Thevenin theorem to both the  circuits evidenced by the hatched rectangles.
[image: Equivalent circuit]

Comment: why would i apply the thevenin theorem also to what branch? i dont understand the transformation you made in the second scheme there must be a condition im not aware of

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: The vertical wire at the right connects the top wire to the bottom wire, so the "Charge X" resistor is really in parallel with the 1.5K resistor.

Comment: @PeterBennett You mean the current that runs in the 3.6k resistor is returnin to the GND of centrale A? same thing for the current that runs thru the 6k resistor is returning back to the centrale B? But if you see in the transformation that Franc did the 1.5k resistor and charge X are in series

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: I think Franc's transformation is incorrect - the 3.6K resistor is clearly in parallel with the 1.5K

Comment: @PeterBennett but if you see in the main circuit, the 3.6K and 6K resistors got the same current running through them or no current, and why please?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: The 3.6K and 6K resistors have different currents - about 3.53  A and 2.85 A, respectively.

Comment: @PeterBennett but they are linked by the same wire in the original scheme how can a wire have different current running through it?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI:The top, right and bottom wires are all one connection - you can slide the component connections along those wires without changing the circuit.  The circuit shown in Franc's "The simplest representation without making any changes is the following:" answer is electrically the same as your original circuit - you will see that the 3.6K and 6K resistors are not in parallel with each other.